# How to receive a Map<String, Integer> from an endpoint using Spring WebClient get?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

How can I receive a Map<String, Integer> from an endpoint web service using WebClient in Spring Boot? Here is my try: (it gives syntax error: `Incompatible equality constraint: Map<String, Integer> and Map`). How can I fix it?

```
public Flux<Map<String, Integer>> findAll(String param1, String param2) {
    return webClient.get()
            .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
                    .path("/url")
                    .queryParam("param1", param1)
                    .queryParam("param2", param2)
                    .build())
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(Map.class);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For generic types, like the Map, you should use [ParameterizedTypeReference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/ParameterizedTypeReference.html) instead of a class in the call to the bodyToFlux method:

```java
public Flux<Map<String, Integer>> findAll(String param1, String param2) {
    return webClient.get()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
            .path("/url")
            .queryParam("param1", param1)
            .queryParam("param2", param2)
            .build())
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {});
}
```

In practice, probably you would like to define a constant for the type reference:

```java
private static final ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Integer>> MAP_TYPE_REF = new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {};

public Flux<Map<String, Integer>> findAll(String param1, String param2) {
    return webClient.get()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
            .path("/url")
            .queryParam("param1", param1)
            .queryParam("param2", param2)
            .build())
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(MAP_TYPE_REF);
}
```